# Selecting multiple rows in PHP using MySQL

Tags: php, admin

Why cant I make this code block work? Even though the connection was successful it still returns Error in your query?

```html
function selectMultiRows($query) 
{    
    if((@$result = mysql_query ($query))==FALSE) 
       { 
        echo "<strong>Error in your query:</strong> <br>$query"; 
    }    
    else 
    {     
        $count = 0; 
        $data = array(); 
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $data[$count] = $row; 
            $count++; 
        } 
            return $data; 
    } 
} 

 
$query = "select * from Users"; 
$returnedData = selectMultiRows($query); 
$totalRecords =  count($returnedData); 

for($i=0;$i<$totalRecords;$i++) 
{ 
    echo $returnedData[$i]["username"] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Simple; you're mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: could you enlighten us as to exactly what's not working?

Comment: I couldnt show any results it says "error in your query".

Comment: What am I mixing sire?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Please use mysqli or PDO.